# Does Postgres have a system table listing precision values for date_trunc?

Tags: postgresql, enums, built-in

The list of valid parameters for `date_truc` found here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC

```
microseconds
milliseconds
second
minute
hour
day
week
month
quarter
year
decade
century
millennium
```

,are they found listen in a system table somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: I just noticed 2 things. 1. Documentation pluralizes microseconds and milliseconds but nothing else. 2. You can pluralize other words and it still accepts it in the function.

Comment: @Nick Barnes Perhaps you should post that as an answer. Nobody else has replied yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported tokens are [hard-coded](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_5/src/backend/utils/adt/datetime.c#L175) and exposed only through a [lookup function](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_5/src/backend/utils/adt/datetime.c#L3716), so there's no way to retrieve the whole list.

The full list is quite a bit longer than the docs suggest, e.g. just for milliseconds, all of these work:

```
select
  date_trunc('ms', now()),
  date_trunc('msec', now()),
  date_trunc('msecs', now()),
  date_trunc('msecond', now()),
  date_trunc('mseconds', now()),
  date_trunc('millisecond', now()),
  date_trunc('milliseconds', now())
```

In fact, only the first [10 characters](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_11_5/src/include/utils/datetime.h#L206) of the token are stored, so this works too:

```
select date_trunc('milliseconzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz', now())
```